# PHP: cant move uploaded file from temp directory

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to upload files to a dynamically created directory using this PHP script, but no bueno.  The script works a treat if I just set the `$storeFolder = 'uploads';`, but won't move them to my new folder.  I've tried creating the folder by hand, even with (eek) permissions set to 777.  No dice even still.

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
function curPageURL()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == "on") {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
$murl = curPageURL();
parse_str($murl, $result);
$storeFolder = 'uploads' . $ds . $result['f'];
if (!is_dir($storeFolder)) {
    mkdir($storeFolder, 775);
}
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . $ds . $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
}
?>
```

Comment: you're missing a zero `mkdir($storeFolder, 0775);` - RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php *bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )*

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Thanks.  add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a zero `mkdir($storeFolder, 0775);`

The manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php states:

> *bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )*